# How do I play videos using original dimensions on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, icloud, video, resolution

I have a number of mp4 videos with poor resolution and/or small dimensions (dimensions: 320 x 240 pixels) that I wish to play on my iPad (4th generation running iOS 10.3.3).

When viewing the videos that have small dimensions in iCloud Drive, the video player in iCloud Drive makes the videos full screen, which makes the videos very blurry. How can I play the videos in their original dimensions instead of full screen?

On a desktop or laptop computer, I can solve this problem by resizing the video player's window to force the video to be as small as I want it to be, but I can't find a solution for the iPad.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running? And, are you using a particular video player app?

Comment: @Monomeeth Edited the question. Added iOS version (10.3.3) and the video player software used (iCloud Drive).

Comment: Did you try downloading the files? Using an alternative player? You could upload to youtube as a last resource...

Comment: @MateusRibeiro Yes, the videos are stored on my iPad (i.e. available through the iCloud Drive app even when I'm offline). I also tried to use the VLC app to play the videos. Uploading to YouTube is not an option because I am frequently offline.